# Multi-site PayPal payments: specifying the business name on card/bank statements and during checkout

Tags: paypal

I have two websites, site (A) & site (B), for example, and both are integrated with one PayPal business account, when I have purchased from website (B) buyer receives the bank transaction message and Paypal payment message labeled with site (A) name rather than (B), please if someone could help and tell how to fix, to get the right website name  (B) when purchase done from (B)  in the PayPal and the bank messages labeled that purchase from the website  (B).

Answer (score 0):

The exact parameter to set when creating the transaction will depend on the integration method, e.g. whether using the [current v2/checkout/orders REST API or JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create), or the classic NVP/SOAP APIs, or an even more legacy [HTML-only integration](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/).

`purchase_units[0].soft_descriptor` , SOFTDESCRIPTOR , or similar is used for the name on card/bank statements

`application_context.brand_name` , BRANDNAME, or similar is used for the business name during the payer's checkout approval

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I integrated with the woocommerce Paypal plugin and I select the standard  method, and the plugin  imported client ID, Secret key, and merchant ID from my account automatically, I don't understand what in this linked page I am not expert, I need to set it easily in the plugin or Paypal developer page

Comment: You might be able to find a WooCommerce plugin that allows you to 'set it easily' -- all I know about are the REST parameters it would be making use of